# Using jBuilder to build a complex array

Tags: ruby-on-rails, jstree, jbuilder

I am using jBuilder and jsTree (https://www.jstree.com/docs/json/) in my Rails app and trying to build an array like this:

```
[
{
  id          : "string" // required
  parent      : "string" // required
  text        : "string" // node text
  icon        : "string" // string for custom
  state       : {
    opened    : boolean  // is the node open
    disabled  : boolean  // is the node disabled
    selected  : boolean  // is the node selected
  },
  li_attr     : {}  // attributes for the generated LI node
  a_attr      : {}  // attributes for the generated A node
},
{...},
{...}
]
```

I did this before with a simple `json.array!` and a do loop with a set of results from my database.  No problems there.  The issue is that I have polymorphic parents i.e. there are different models.  I will equate this to an example where I have a 'Products' and 'Equipment' and they all have comments nested below.  I want to list all the Projects (with child comments) then list all the Equipment and then child comments for them.  I essentially need a loop like this:

```
[

projects do |p|
  json.id id
  json.parent "#"
  ...
end

equipment do |e|
  json.id id
  json.parent "#"
  ...
end

comments do |c|
  json.id id
  json.parent c.parent_id
  ...
end

]
```

This way I can build the hash of data for jsTree to parse.  The docs for jBuilder are not great and not sure how or of I can do this.

Answer (score 0):

I would just skip jBuilder. Its slow as heck and do you really need a super awkward DSL to build JSON objects? After all Rubys hashes and arrays map cleanly to JSON types.

```
class JsTreeSerializer
  # @param [Array] records
  # @param [Mixed] context - used to call view helpers
  def initialize(records, context: nil)
    @records = records
    @context = context
  end

  def serialize
    json = @records.map do |record|
      { 
         id: record.id,
         parent: record.parent_id,
         icon: context.image_url('icon.gif')
         # ...
      }
    end
  end
end
```

Usage:

```
class MyController 
  def index
     @records = get_all_the_types
     respond_to do |f|
       format.json do
         render json: JsTreeSerializer.new(
           @records, 
           context: view_context
         ).serialize
       end
     end
  end
end
```

Answer (score 0):

It ended up being as simple as:

```
json.array!
json.(@projects) do |p|
  json.id id
  json.parent "#"
  ...
end
json.(@equipment) do |e|
  json.id id
  json.parent "#"
  ...
end
json.(@comments) do |c|
  json.id id
  json.parent c.parent_id
  ...
end
```